# get image to display on same row as text in a GRID

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, layout, grid

why does the below code have the picture and the labels on different rows...I want them all on the same row in different columns...so keeping the labels where they are in horizontal order ...and moving the image down to the same level

Desired:

```
       Vodka
       700ml
Image  13.99
```

current:
[image]

```
 <Grid RowSpacing="25">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding OffersList}" PeekAreaInsets="20">
            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="10"/>
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame CornerRadius="30" Margin="20" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="500">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Source="{Binding Img}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Red" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Des}" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" FontSize="Title"  HorizontalOptions="End" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding FullPrice, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Pink" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

Comment: There is no Grid in your XAML.  Grid.Row and Grid.Column don't do anything if you're not using a Grid

Comment: further, you Labels are all in the same row/col so they will just stack up on top one another

Comment: sorry updated missing code...yes i want them to be all horizontally aligned so should they not be on the same row?>

Comment: that Grid is the container for your entire page, not a grid for the content within the Carousel.  You are using a StackLayout in the Carousel, so everything just stack on one another.  The labels are all in the same row AND column, not just the same row.  Grid.Row and Grid.Column only apply to elements that are direct children of the Grid.  See my answer below

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not actually using a `Grid`, you are using a `StackLayout`

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefintions>
    <ColumnDefintion Width="25*" />
    <ColumnDefintion Width="25*" />
    <ColumnDefintion Width="25*" />
    <ColumnDefintion Width="25*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefintions>
  <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Source="{Binding Img}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
  <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Red" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
  <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Des}" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" FontSize="Title"  HorizontalOptions="End" />
  <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding FullPrice, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Pink" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the layout you want above,you should move the `Grid` into your `<CarouselView.ItemTemplate>`,like:

```
<CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame CornerRadius="30" Margin="20" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="500">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="25">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"  Source="{Binding Img}" WidthRequest="100"  Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Red" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Des}" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" FontSize="Title"  HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding FullPrice, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Pink" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
</CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```